# Slave could not connect to Master regionserver - connection refused

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I tried to set up HBase on my Hadoop installation and I have bug in slave logs connected with regionserver:

```
2016-01-09 23:54:59,829 WARN  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: error telling master we are up
com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

my /etc/hosts

```
10.156.207.48   hadoop-master
10.156.207.31   hadoop-slave-1
```

my hbase-site.xml (on master)

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>hadoop-master, hadoop-slave-1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
```

my hbase-site.xml (on slave)

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/hbase</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Please for any help how can I fix it?

Comment: why don't you have zk config for the slave?  i would think that was required